Update Profile in Laravel with additional columns
I want to create dynamic auth by adding an update profile function, but after I tried it, nothing changed.
I have tried the put and post methods, but the results are still the same. Is there a special method to create an update form from Laravel's default auth ?
Controller :
public function update(Request $request,User $user)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'nullable|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'current_password' => 'required_with:password|current_password',
        'foto' => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png|max:100000',
    ]);

     //for user
    $user->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    // Cek apakah password lama benar jika password baru diisi
    if ($request->filled('password')) {
        if (!Hash::check($request->input('current_password'), $user->password)) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['current_password' => 'The provided password does not match our records.']);
        }

        $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
    }

    //for profile
    $user->role = $request->input('role');
    // Jika ada file foto yang diunggah, simpan
    if (isset($user['foto']) && $user['foto'] instanceof \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile) {
        if ($user['foto']->isValid()) {
            // Simpan foto dan dapatkan path relatif
            $path = $user['foto']->store('foto_user', 'public');
            // Simpan path relatif ke database
            $user->foto = $path;
            $user->save();
        }
    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('profile')->with('pesan', 'Data Berhasil Diperbarui !!!');
}

View
<div class="modal fade" id="updateProfileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateProfileModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateProfileModalLabel">Update Profile</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Form untuk update profil -->
            <form action="{{ route('updateprofile') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" required>
                    @error('name')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" required>
                    @error('email')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="role">Role</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="role" name="role" required>
                        <option value="1" {{ Auth::user()->role == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Admin Up2d</option>
                        <option value="2" {{ Auth::user()->role == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Har</option>
                        <option value="3" {{ Auth::user()->role == 3 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Perencanaan</option>
                        <option value="4" {{ Auth::user()->role == 4 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Fasop</option>
                        <option value="5" {{ Auth::user()->role == 5 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Operasi</option>
                        <option value="6" {{ Auth::user()->role == 6 ? 'selected' : '' }}>UP3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="current_password">Current Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current_password" name="current_password" placeholder="Enter your current password">
                    @error('current_password')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Leave empty to keep current password" autocomplete="new-password">
                    @error('password')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm New Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation">
                    @error('password_confirmation')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group custom-file-button">
                        <label class="input-group-text">Profile Photo</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control @error('foto') is-invalid @enderror" name="foto">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            @error('foto')
                            {{ $message }}
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if(Auth::user()->foto)
                        <img src="{{ Storage::url(Auth::user()->foto) }}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                    @else
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/default/user.png') }}" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Profile</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

And Route
Route::post('/profile/update', [App\Http\Controllers\SettingsController::class, 'update'])->name('updateprofile');

So, what do you think is wrong and missing from my code?
